# Adding 1 to a field in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL query I'm running. I want to add `1` to a field called `articleswritten`.

I get this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''users' SET articleswritten = articleswritten + 1 WHERE `id` = '1'' at line 1

Code:

```
$sql = "UPDATE 'users' SET articleswritten = articleswritten + 1 WHERE `id` = '$userid'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

I can't find an issue. Am I blind?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `users` is a table name and should therefore not be quoted in single quotes.  `UPDATE users SET ....` It can be optionally quoted with backticks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/mysql-when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks

Answer (score 0):

This should either be

```
UPDATE `users`
```

Or just

```
UPDATE users
```

The single quotes make the table name invalid.  Everything else in the query is okay.

---

However, your query is vulnerable to injection.  Instead of using ext/mysql, you should use properly parameterized queries with PDO or mysqli

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to single quote the table name here. This should do

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET articleswritten = articleswritten + 1 WHERE id = '$userid'";
```